# why perform selective read on the inotify instance using select() call

Tags: c++

Based on this http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/inotify-c-program-example/

Example: https://gist.github.com/pkrnjevic/6016356#file-inotify-example-cpp

```
while ( run )
{
    select( fd + 1, &watch_set, NULL, NULL, NULL ); // non-blocking

    int length = read( fd, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN );
    if ( length < 0 )
    {
        perror( "read" );
    }
```

VS

```
while ( run )
{
    int length = read( fd, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN ); // blocking
    if ( length < 0 )
    {
        perror( "read" );
    }
```

Question> I need to monitor a changes in the directory. What is the key difference between the select+read and the read ONLY method above. As far as I know, the select + read is not blocking read and it will keep polling this calling again and again. Does this select+read really give me any benefit?

Thank you

Comment: If you have nothing else to do, use the second method. If you have anything else you might want to do other than wait, use the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is effectively the same. The first version will block untill descriptor is readable, and than read (won't block at this reading). The second version will block in read. Second version is likely to be (miniscule) faster, since it does one kernel call instead of two.